# Angularjs, JavaEE and http request with inherited objects?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, http, inheritance

I work on webapp and can't find solution or example of my problem. 
I use AngularJS, RestServis and JavaEE . My problem is how to send inherited object with superObject

In java I have two classes:

```
public class User{

protected String userName; 
protected String userSurename;  
..
..
}
```

Second class is a subclass

```
public class Worker extends User{

protected int idWorker; 
protected String position; 
..
..
}
```

in Angular controller I have

```
$scope.user = {
userName : "jon" ,
userSurename :"dep"  }

$scope.worker= {
idWorker: 88 ,
position: "seller"  }
```

and I use http protocol to send data on server side like this

```
this.saveWorker = function(worker) {
    return $http({
    method:'post',
    url:this.apiBasicUrl,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: worker
    });
};
```

How in Angular in data to put one object and on Java side get worker object with user data also ? Can I , object like in java , make in angular with inherited ?

Answer (score 0):

On Angular side, I suggest using `$resource` for communication with REST API:

```
var Worker = $resource('/worker/:workerId', {workerId:'@id'});
//get
var worker = Worker.get({workerId:123}, function() {
    worker.abc = true;
    //save
    worker.$save();
});
```

On server side you should have a REST endpoint that is supposed to pick up these objects:

```
@Path("/worker")
public class WorkerService {

    @GET
    @Path("{workerId}")
    public Worker getWorker(@PathParm("workerId") Integer workerId) {
        //implement
    }

    @POST
    public void saveWorker(Worker worker) {
        //implement
    }

}
```

This might not work out of the box. You will most likely need *Jackson* provider to enable REST to "translate" JSON into Java objects.

See this example: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/